# Creating extensible code

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am making an application where the user is prompt at some point to create a new file (object not file in OS). That file represents one of several subclasses of an abstract class named `FilePack`.
The user will choose the type of the file from a list (in a `JOptionPane`) then that option is forwarded to a method which will create the appropriate subclass.

An example:
User clicks on "create new file" button. `JOptionPane` comes with a list of available `FilePack` subclasses. User selects "Type A". Selection forwarded to method which creates the appropriate subclass.

Which would be the optimal way of handling this operation which will allow the code to work when introducing new `FilePack` subclasses without having to go everywhere and changing bits of code?

(at this point you have to change the list in JOptionPane and the method creating the subclasses, but its possible changes will need to happen on more places later in development)

Also, is it possible to get two inputs from a JOptionPane? One using textfield and one from list ?Im only able to do one at time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd propose to use enum for options:

```
enum FilePackSubclassOption {

    TYPE_A() {
        @Override
        public FilePack createFilePack() {
            return new FilePackTypeA();
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "Type A";
        }
    };

    public abstract FilePack createFilePack();
    public abstract String getName();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

To get all options you can use `FilePackClassOption.values()` as `options` parameter in `JOptionPane`. And when you add new subclass of `FilePack` your only need to add new value to enum and implement 2 methods.

Example of use:

```
public void chooseFilePack() {
    Object selection = JOptionPange.showInputDialog(null, 
                           "Select file pack type", "File pack", 0, null, 
                           FilePackSubclassOption.values(), null);
    if (selection != null) {
        return ((FilePackSubclassOption)selection).createFilePack();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I believe for this case i like this solution better although Ill have to test it. Is it possible to also receive a second input from same JOptionPane which will be the name/title for the FilePack ? User needs to type that . Atm i just make one JOptionPane that gets the name and then one with a list. It would be nice to have both things in 1

Comment: @latusaki. User can either type name or select it from list. Am I right?

Comment: From the list you select the type(subclass) of FilePack. The typed name is the name which will appear on GUI for that object(the files are shown in a tree). So i want in same JOptionPane to select the type to be created and type its name.

Comment: @latusaki. Hm, it's another question. I think you need to create your own dialog where you can add input field for name and select field to type. I believe `JOptionPane` doesn't have options to show 2 inputs at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the best solution for this scenario would be to use the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). This works by having an abstract class `FileFactory`, with a method producing generic `File`s. You then create a concrete factoriy, creating implementations of `File`. Example:

```
public interface FileFactory {
   public File createFile();
}

public abstract class File {
}

public class File1 extends File {
}

public class File2 extends File {
}

public class ConcreteFileFactory implements FileFactory {
    public File createFile(int fileType) { 
        switch(fileType) {
            case 1: return new File1();
            case 2: return new File2();
            // etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Adding new `File`s now only requires you to add the new concrete `File` class and the appropriate case in the `FileFactory` implementation.

Then in your GUI you have something like:

```
int type = // get an int from selected type of file
File file = new ConcreteFileFactory().createFile(type);
```

There are many variations to this pattern, this is just an example I adapted from [Applied Java Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130935387).

Comment: Your answer misses the most important part IMHO: how to get the appropriate factory from the file type selected by the user. If you don't say that, and the OP uses a chain of if to get the appropriate factory, the factory isn't useful, and a direct constructor call is sufficient.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Isn't the part with the switch what you mean?

Comment: Not at all. The factory isn't useful if you still need a switch. The call in each switch could be replaced with `file = new File1()`, making the factory completely useless. The advantage of this pattern is that you can associate (using a `Map<String, FileFactory>` for example) each type with the associated factory. And thus, each time you need a file, you just call `map.get(type).createFile()`. This map should be encapsulated inside a unique FileFactory object, which would have a `File createFile(String type)` method.

Comment: Thanks for this example I'm sure I can use it on another part of the application I got in mind although for this case I believe the enum does same thing but simpler.

Comment: @JB Nizet: What if the switch is moved inside a single factory?

Comment: Then it's OK, but all the other factories, which create a unique type of file, become completely unnecessary.